# Entrance animation for circles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Let's consider I have few divs organized this way:

[image]

```css
#absolute-canvas a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
  border-radius: 100%;    
  background: black;
}
.deg0 { 
  transform: translate(12em);
} /* 12em = half the width of the wrapper */
.deg45 { 
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(12em) rotate(-45deg);
}
.deg135 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(12em) rotate(-135deg);
}
.deg180 { 
  transform: translate(-12em);
}
.deg225 { 
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(12em) rotate(-225deg);
}
.deg315 { 
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(12em) rotate(-315deg);
}
```

```html
<section id="absolute-canvas">

  <img src="./images/logoWithShadow.png" id="logo" class="img-responsive animated zoomIn" alt="" title="СП ФИНКИ" />
  <div id="nav-container">
    <a href='#' class='deg0'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg45'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg135'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg180'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg225'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg315'></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

I want to animate it in such a way that when the central image is hovered, the outside circles to appear with a certain animation - from the center of the central image to move outwards to their respective positions (or in a circular way entrance, doesn't have to be a straight line).

Is there any library that has such an animation already implemented, or any ideas on how I can accomplish such an animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very broad but here is one idea:

```css
#absolute-canvas a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; 
  left: 50%;
  width: 4em; 
  height: 4em;
  margin: -2em;
  border-radius: 100%;    
  background: black;
  transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
#absolute-canvas:hover a {
  opacity: 1;
}
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg0 { 
  transform: translate(12em);
} /* 12em = half the width of the wrapper */
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg45 { 
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(12em);
}
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg135 {
  transform: rotate(135deg) translate(12em);
}
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg180 { 
  transform: rotate(180deg) translate(12em);
}
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg225 { 
  transform: rotate(225deg) translate(12em);
}
#absolute-canvas:hover .deg315 { 
  transform: rotate(315deg) translate(12em);
}
```

```html
<section id="absolute-canvas">

  <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" id="logo" class="img-responsive animated zoomIn" alt="" title="СП ФИНКИ" />
  <div id="nav-container">
    <a href='#' class='deg0'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg45'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg135'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg180'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg225'></a>
    <a href='#' class='deg315'></a>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, turned out to look pretty darn cool :D The only issue is those circles contain icons and when the hover animation is finished the angle needs to be kept (at the moment the icons are rotated since the circle rotates)

Comment: You would have to apply a separate rotation to the icons to counteract the rotation of the circle

Comment: It might look something like this depending on your actual markup https://jsfiddle.net/o3fny0yn/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/jcLaq3cv/) You can use the following CSS selector

```
 img:hover ~ #nav-container a
```

To select the balls only on image hover. I set their initial position to 0 and animate the translate on image hover.

Initial state

```
.deg0 { 
   transform: translate(0);
}
```

Hover

```
img:hover ~ #nav-container .deg0 { 
    transform: translate(12em);
}
```